# jQuery Ajax scripts knock out each other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have a little problem with my code. I want to make an ajax based website where you don't need to refresh page. But the two js knock out each other or something is wrong because I can log in but when I am trying to logout, nothing happends, but if I refresh (and I am still loged in) I can logout but now when the login form appear I can't login. Here is my javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".login").click(function() {
        var dataString = $("#loginform").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checklogin.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#pirossavon").html(html);
                $('#content').load(document.URL + ' #content');
            }
        });

    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".logout").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checklogin.php",
            data: "logout=1",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#pirossavon").html(html);
                $('#content').load(document.URL + ' #content');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

As you can see, after a success ajax, I am reloading the header (where is the login form and the details if you log in) and the content div of my site.

Comment: You destroy your listeners when you replace the html

Comment: Okay, I understand the problem. But how should i change it? It is clear that I need a logout button, href or something when I log in. But If I cant replace the html, I dont know how the content should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both script tags inside the document before any AJAX calls are made?

The problem might be that you're not using [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.login', function() {

    // AJAX

  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.logout', function() {

    // AJAX

  });
});
```

Since the logout button isn't present before logging in, you're event handler isn't attached to any object. After refresh, the event is attached, but now the login button doesn't have an event handler. So you can log out, but now you can't log in. By attaching the event to the document (or any parent of both buttons that doesn't get replaced during an AJAX call would be good) and delegating it to the respective button, your event handlers are attached, even when one of the buttons isn't present in the document **yet**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Thank you, I am beginner in JS. I learned something new again!